# mysql SELECT columns but use WHERE to only one

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT  i.d, COUNT(id) AS dr, COUNT(id2) AS dn, SUM(eq) AS eq_sum, COUNT(thx) AS thx_count 
FROM dsd
  INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(id) AS d FROM ds
    ) i
```

Now I want to use WHERE only to column `thx` like WHERE thx="y" , so that it will count only all values with "y".

But If I just add WHERE at the end of the query it will affect other columns as well which I don't want to.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then change your `COUNT(thx) AS thx_count` to below using `CASE` expression like

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN thx = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS thx_count
```

(OR)

```
SUM(CASE WHEN thx = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS thx_count
```

Comment: thank you. The second option only works for me, I also found this `SUM(if(thx = 'y',1,0)) AS thx_count`

Comment: @felixRo, that `if(...` is kind a shorthand of `CASE` expression

Comment: would you be able to show me how to add a condition for all columns which would show all values only for the current month? (in both tables `dsd` and `ds` I have the field date_add (which is the type of datetime)

Comment: ok I think I found solution `WHERE month(date_add) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW()))`